# Why are decimals dropped in my Qt App in std::vector<double> when the data comes from MySQL?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, c++11, vector

In my Qt application I use a C++ function that fills a `std::vector<double>` with data from a MySQL database. The function uses MySQL Connector/C++ and does the following:

```
void create_price(sql::Connection *con, std::string database, std::string table, std::vector<double> &price_vec)
{
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;

        std::string use_database = "USE " + database;

        stmt = con->createStatement();
        stmt->execute(use_database);

        use_database = "SELECT Time,LastVolume,LastPrice FROM "+ table +" WHERE LastVolume >0 OR LastPrice >0 ORDER BY Time ASC";

        res = stmt->executeQuery(use_database); //will return many rows

        while (res->next()) {         
                price_vec.push_back(res->getDouble("LastPrice")); 
        }
}
```

When I call this function with any `std::vector<double>` in my plain C++ application I get flawless results. However, when I call this function in my Qt application the passed vector is filled with ints. The decimal part is dropped!

It seems to be an issue with the MySQL part, since this test function returns proper doubles, even when called from within my Qt application.

```
void double_test(std::vector &doublevec){ 
    //just some doubles to test.
    std::vector<double> doublevec;
    doublevec.push_back(1.4);
    doublevec.push_back(5.324);
}
```

Is it possible that the double returned by the MySQL query is not actually a real double and therefore not compatible with Qt?

Any hint on what I can do to understand the problem better would also help.

EDIT: The part that establishes the connection looks like this

C++:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;

    driver = get_driver_instance();

    try{
        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306","root","pass");
        cout << "Connection established" << endl;
    }
    catch(...){
        cout << "Exception: Couldnt' connect to MySQL server. Check if it is running" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    vector<double> price;

    create_price(con,"database","table",price); 

    driver->threadEnd();

    delete con;

    cout << "Job done" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Qt:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
// con and driver are private class members
        driver = get_driver_instance();

        try{
            con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306","root","pass");
            std::cout << "Connection established" << std::endl;
        }
        catch(...){
            std::cout << "Exception: Couldnt' connect to MySQL server. Check if it is running" << std::endl;
        }

        std::vector<double> price; //this vector now has doubles without decimals.

        create_price(con,"database","table",price);

        setupPlot();
}
```

Comment: So, same function in both cases?  How do you set up the database connection?  Differently?

Comment: Are the values in the database stored as doubles? Also why not use the SQL wrapper that Qt provides? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-programming.html

Comment: @Yakk The function is in a header file that I include. The connection is established in `main` through `sql::connection *con` in the case of the plain C++ code that I use or in the case of my Qt code it's in the constructor of my `MainWindow`

Comment: @A.Fagrell Yes the values are stored as doubles. Or is MySQL double a different thing? I have this function in a header file along with other MySQL functions I wrote in C++. I would prefer to reuse this instead of reimpleminting it with the Qt wrapper.

Comment: `sql::connection*con` is the type.  I mean *the code* that creates the connection.  In what way is it different?  If you, in MainWindow, create the connection then run the above code, do you get the same problem?  How about doing the same in `main`?  What happens if you make a new Qt project and only make the connection and run the above code?

Comment: @Yakk thanks for your help. Check my edited question to see how the connection is established. I just tried to run the plain C++ part in `main` of my Qt project, and it leads to the same problem. Also in a new project. Something in Qt seems not to work with this MySQL part.